# Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 (Windows) cannot run/ install app on any devices

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, upgrade

[image]

I just updated Android Studio to new version (*Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1*) and when I try to install the application, it just run gradle build.
I'm not sure it is cache, my PC or Android Studio issue.
If anyone also have this kind of problem and solution, please let me know.

After waiting project being built, it just end with build successful message without install the app to device like bellow screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

I had a similar issue and found out that after installing Dolphin, for some reason the run configurations were amended.

Check your Run Configuration, maybe it's not configured to run the default Activity.

In the toolbar, click the dropdown and then choose Edit Configurations
[image: Edit Configurations dropdown]

Then in the window that opens, select the run configuration you want to edit. In my case, it was "zapp" and then under General tab, see that under Launch Options -> Launch it says: Default Activity.

[image: Edit Configurations dialog]

If that still doesn't fix it for you, check the Deploy option above it.

Comment: In the module dropdown box the only option it gives me is "<no module>".  How do I change this?  I'm using Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch1 built on September 29, 2022.